# Variable length and position command line arguments

Tags: c++, position, command-line-arguments

So, quick question:
I am tasked with making a program that reads in a file, does some fancy things, and writes out to an html file with the re-purposed text, all simple stuff.
Furthermore the program must be able to accept up to four command line arguments (but a minumum of two). The executable of course, the file it is reading in, the file name it will be reading out to, and finally a "-r" argument for more information on the file (the amount of paragraphs, etc).

So the question I have is as follows:
the "-r" argument can be anywhere in the arguments (as long as it comes after argv[0] of course), or it can be completely non-existent (as can the output file name).

This is still simple to do, a little tedious writing a bunch of if's or even a switch or two, but I can't help but think that there may be an easier way to accomplish this, rather than having a plethora of if statements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I also suppose you don't need any code considering I don't exactly have a problem.)

Comment: It would be nice to have the relevant code that you do have surrounding your issues. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: There are command line parsing options all over the internet. Find one you line and use it.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman The thing is, I don'y have an issue, just a simple question.

Comment: Boost `program options` might be an overkill here. But you can try it. Esier option is `getopts`

Comment: @Named Thank you, I've already looked into Boost program options, but not getopts, so I shall look into that

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is roughly how one might do it without a library:

GCC 4.8.2: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char* input = nullptr;
  char* output = nullptr;
  char* r_arg = nullptr;
  --argc; ++argv; // Skip the program name.
  const char* def_in = "default in";
  const char* def_out = "default out";
  const char* def_r = "default r";

  while (0 < argc) {
    if (std::string(argv[0]) == "-r") {
      // This code requires a space after the "-r", which is unusual.
      ++argv;
      --argc;
      r_arg = argv[0]; }
    else if (input == nullptr) {
      input = argv[0]; }
    else if (output == nullptr) {
      output = argv[0]; }
    else {
      std::cerr << "error: unexpected arg '" << argv[0] << "'\n"; }

    ++argv;
    --argc; }

  if (input == nullptr) {
    input = const_cast<char*>(def_in); }

  if (output == nullptr) {
    output = const_cast<char*>(def_out); }

  if (r_arg == nullptr) {
    r_arg = const_cast<char*>(def_r); }

  std::cout << "input: " << input << "\n"
            << "output: " << output << "\n"
            << "r arg: " << r_arg << "\n";
  return 0; }
```